# Spark dataframe self-joins are producing empty dataframe as a result

Tags: apache-spark

Below is my data in csv which I read into dataframe.

```
id,pid,pname,ppid
 1,  1,    5,  -1
 2,  1,    7,  -1
 3,  2,    9,   1
 4,  2,   11,   1
 5,  3,    5,   1
 6,  4,    7,   2
 7,  1,    9,   3
```

I am reading that data into a dataframe `data_df`. I am tryng to do a self-join on different columns. But the results dataframes are empty. Have tried multiple options.

Below is my code. Only the last joined4 is producing the result.

```
val joined = data_df.as("first").join(data_df.as("second")).where( col("first.ppid") === col("second.pid"))
joined.show(50, truncate = false)

val joined2 = data_df.as("first").join(data_df.as("second"), col("first.ppid") === col("second.pid"), "inner")
joined2.show(50, truncate = false)

val df1 = data_df.as("df1")
val df2 = data_df.as("df2")
val joined3  = df1.join(df2, $"df1.ppid" === $"df2.id")
joined3.show(50, truncate = false)

val joined4  = data_df.as("df1").join(data_df.as("df2"), Seq("id"))
joined4.show(50, truncate = false)
```

Below are the output of joined, joined2, joined3, joined4 respectively :

```
+---+---+-----+----+---+---+-----+----+
|id |pid|pname|ppid|id |pid|pname|ppid|
+---+---+-----+----+---+---+-----+----+
+---+---+-----+----+---+---+-----+----+

+---+---+-----+----+---+---+-----+----+
|id |pid|pname|ppid|id |pid|pname|ppid|
+---+---+-----+----+---+---+-----+----+
+---+---+-----+----+---+---+-----+----+

+---+---+-----+----+---+---+-----+----+
|id |pid|pname|ppid|id |pid|pname|ppid|
+---+---+-----+----+---+---+-----+----+
+---+---+-----+----+---+---+-----+----+

+---+---+-----+----+---+-----+----+
|id |pid|pname|ppid|pid|pname|ppid|
+---+---+-----+----+---+-----+----+
| 1 |  1|    5|  -1|  1|    5|  -1|
| 2 |  1|    7|  -1|  1|    7|  -1|
| 3 |  2|    9|   1|  2|    9|   1|
| 4 |  2|   11|   1|  2|   11|   1|
| 5 |  3|    5|   1|  3|    5|   1|
| 6 |  4|    7|   2|  4|    7|   2|
| 7 |  1|    9|   3|  1|    9|   3|
+---+---+-----+----+---+-----+----+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, later on figured out that the spaces in the csv were causing the issue. If I create a correctly structured csv of the initial data, the problem disappears.

Correct csv format as follows.

```
id,pid,pname,ppid
1,1,5,-1
2,1,7,-1
3,2,9,1
4,2,1,1
5,3,5,1
6,4,7,2
7,1,9,3
```

Ideally, I can also use the option to ignore leading whitespaces as shown in the following answer :

```
val data_df = spark.read
  .schema(dataSchema)
  .option("mode", "FAILFAST")
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace", "true")
  .csv(dataSourceName)
```

[pySpark (v2.4) DataFrameReader adds leading whitespace to column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53656237/pyspark-v2-4-dataframereader-adds-leading-whitespace-to-column-names/53656633#53656633)