# pySpark (v2.4) DataFrameReader adds leading whitespace to column names

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Here is a snippet of a CSV file that I have:

```
"Index", "Living Space (sq ft)", "Beds", "Baths", "Zip", "Year", "List Price ($)"
 1,       2222,                   3,      3.5,    32312, 1981,    250000
 2,       1628,                   3,      2,      32308, 2009,    185000
 3,       3824,                   5,      4,      32312, 1954,    399000
 4,       1137,                   3,      2,      32309, 1993,    150000
 5,       3560,                   6,      4,      32309, 1973,    315000
```

Oddly, when I perform the following pySpark (v2.4) statements, the header column names (minus the first column) have leading whitespaces. I've tried different `quote` and `escape` `options`, but to no avail.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to strip the extra whitespaces on load? Thank you in advance!

```
>>> csv_file = '/tmp/file.csv'

>>> spark_reader.format('csv')

>>> spark_reader.option("inferSchema", "true")
>>> spark_reader.option("header", "true")
>>> spark_reader.option("quote", '"')

>>> df = spark_reader.load(csv_file)

>>> df.columns
['Index', ' "Living Space (sq ft)"', ' "Beds"', ' "Baths"', ' "Zip"', ' "Year"', ' "List Price ($)"']
```

Comment: That's because there's a space after the comma in your header (the separator is the `,`). Set the [`ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader) parameter to `True` (defaults to `False`)

Comment: @pault Oh I see. Why don't you post it as an answer so I can upvote and accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs for [`pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader), you can use the `ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace` parameter.

> ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace – A flag indicating whether or not leading whitespaces from values being read should be skipped. If None is set, it uses the default value, false.

In your case, you just need to add:

```python
spark_reader.option("ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace", "true")
```

Comment: Excellent @pault. That resolved my issue. I never had spaces surrounding the commas before, but there's a first time for everything =:) Thank you very much.